# How to get orders from a specific date , Magento 1 issue

Tags: magento-1, collection

This is my code:

```
....
 ->addFieldToFilter('scheduled_at', ['eq' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 week'))])
```

I want to get all of the order which delivery date is 2  weeks from now.

This returns me this query:

```
WHERE `scheduled_at` = '2017-05-10');
```

I want to get this:

```
WHERE (date(`scheduled_at`) = '2017-05-10');
```

How can I do that? All the info which I found on stackoverflow was about between x and y or greater or less then x. I want equal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you can try to use `addExpressionFieldToSelect`

```
$collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
    'date_scheduled_at',
    'date({{scheduled_at}})',
    array('scheduled_at' => 'scheduled_at')
);
$collection->getSelect()->having('date_scheduled_at = ?', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 week')));
```

Comment: instead of `strtotime('+2 week')` I changed it with `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 week'))` and it worked . thx :) !

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited the answer on your suggestion. Glad it worked.